# R: List key value mappings switched

Tags: r

Right now, I'm using lists as dictionaries mapping basketball team names to win rates). Somehow, after I'm finished processing the data I have, the key/value mappings are switched, so that the values themselves are correct, but keys don't map to their correct values. Is there any common mistake that might cause this to happen?

Here's some of the code I'm using, where the csv has the information in names(games).

```
games <- read.csv(game_pathname, header = FALSE)
names(games) <- c("GameDate", "DateCount", "HomeID", "AwayID", "HomePts", "AwayPts", "HomeAbbr", "AwayAbbre", "HomeName", "AwayName")
wins <- list()

for (team in unique(games$HomeName)) {
    wins[[team]] <- 0
}

for (i in 1:nrow(games)) {
    if (games$HomePts[i] > games$AwayPts[i]) {
        wins[[games$HomeName[[i]]]] <- wins[[games$HomeName[[i]]]] + 1
    } else {
        wins[[games$AwayName[[i]]]] <- wins[[games$AwayName[[i]]]] + 1
    }
}

>str(games)
'data.frame':   10303 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ GameDate : chr  "2008-11-10" "2008-11-10" "2008-11-11" "2008-11-11" ...
 $ DateCount: int  0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 ...
 $ HomeID   : int  113 76 113 76 124 168 312 329 272 329 ...
 $ AwayID   : int  98 234 234 98 204 204 233 167 160 233 ...
 $ HomePts  : int  63 80 76 97 60 76 82 66 80 78 ...
 $ AwayPts  : int  65 49 57 54 73 56 58 70 73 68 ...
 $ HomeAbbr : chr  "ham" "dau" "ham" "dau" ... 
 $ AwayAbbre: chr  "gab" "paq" "paq" "gab" ...
 $ HomeName : chr  "Houston" "Duke" "Houston" "Duke" ...
 $ AwayName : chr  "Georgia Southern" "Presbyterian" "Presbyterian" "Georgia Southern" ...
```

Comment: The improper usage of factors comes to mind.

Comment: I don't think I'm using factors, unless they're somehow implicit within lists? All I'm basically doing is looking up dictionary values and updating them with some simple arithmetic.

Comment: Factors often pop up when you input data because of the default setting for stringsAsFactor=TRUE. So numeric data that has a single character in its column ends up as a factor that looks like numbers. Likewise that default also operates with the data.frame function.

Comment: You already posted about the dictionary earlier today.  I really think that if you posted just a small snippet (use subset and dput) of what you've got a hash table could really make light work of what you want.

Comment: Could be NULL filled lists, too. Show us `str(your_list)`

Comment: I tried using a hash table instead and got the same result. I'm pretty unfamiliar with R, but I was under the assumption that lists in R are basically hash tables in other languages.

Comment: Why is the default setting for stringsAsFactors=TRUE?  It strikes me as causing way more heartache then help...

Comment: Here's a subset of my list:

List of 347
 $ Houston               : num 35
 $ Duke                  : num 56
 $ IUPUI                 : num 33
 $ Michigan              : num 33
 $ UCLA                  : num 39

Comment: @Justin Because that's what R Core finds most useful and intuitive. And it's probably to fundamental default to change now, too much stuff would need to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
str(yourbasketballdataset)
```

to check whether there are any factors in your dataset. Make also sure to check

```
?relevel
?levels
?as.factor
```

when trying to learn a bit about factors. Are you a Python guy (I mean since you use the term dictionary)? Even though I don't understand why you use lists (probably data.frame would be sufficient) you might want to look at `lapply` for processing lists.

Note that factors are not implicit within list, but are often created when data occurs that can easily be interpreted as categorical data – factor is just the R term for categorical. Maybe, you can try to post a reproducible example. I know it's some work to create one – but it's worth the hustle – particularly if you are a beginner. And cause it's basketball I might even have intrinsic motivation to check it on a sunday :)

Comment: I added a code snippet above. I'm doing an assignment where we're supposed to use R, but I'm pretty used to doing things in Python, so I'm pretty sure I'm not doing this the R way.

Comment: Use subset and dput to provide a bit of the data you're working with.  And no this is probably not the most eloquent or fastest way to do this in R.  Also it may be easier to figure out what you want by 1) explaining exactly what you want in words 2) provide a sample output data frame as well.  It's more likely you'll get a usable response if you provide us with a reproducible example and make clear what you want to get out of this.  If you have to figure it out from your code it makes it a lot more difficult.